# jquery autocomplete highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How can I make my jquery autocomplete highlight what the user is typing in in any autocompleted results? The code I am using is:

```
    $("#keyword").autocomplete({ 
        source: "ajax/autocomplete.php?action=keyword", 
        minLength: 2 
    });
```

Tried this implemented from the link tomasz posted:

```
    $("#keyword").autocomplete({ 
        source: "ajax/autocomplete.php?action=keyword", 
        highlight: function(value, term) { 
    return value.replace(new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi"),'<b>$1</b>'); 
    },
        minLength: 2 
    });
```

No luck there either. jQuery autocomplete seems to hate me.

Update: Thanks to David Murdoch, I now have an answer! See @Herman's copy of the answer below.

Comment: The code on [this site might help you](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: If you found the solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it. This is considered completely fine; see [this FAQ on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/17467#17467).

Comment: @Jaime: Please go ahead and move your answer to... an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks goes to David Murdoch at http://www.vervestudios.co/ for providing this useful answer:

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function( ul, item){
  var term = this.term.split(' ').join('|');
  var re = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi") ;
  var t = item.label.replace(re,"<b>$1</b>");
  return $( "<li></li>" )
     .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
     .append( "<a>" + t + "</a>" )
     .appendTo( ul );
};
$("#keyword").autocomplete({ 
  source: "ajax/autocomplete.php?action=keyword", 
  minLength: 2 
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Herman Schaaf I am still getting used to SO and did not see the comment about this.  :(

Comment: This works fine , but what if I want to highlight only the text that the user has typed. for example if the word list conatains a word "abcabc" and the user has typed "ab" I want that only the first "ab" string will be highlight. want should I changed ?

Comment: I've seen a lot of ugly ways of solving this, this is definitively the prettiest I've seen so far. Implemented!

Comment: heads up this breaks if the user inputs parenthesis:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(()/: Unterminated group

Answer (score 2):

Thought somone might find this useful. it's a complete HTML doc that makes uses of the above principles. I used it as a protoype for some of my work.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!--

        orders.html simply returns the following text

        Basketball#Football#Baseball#Helicopter#gubbins#harry potter#banyan


    -->

    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>AutoComplete Box with jQuery</title>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function loadData() {

                var sURL = "orders.htm";

                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

                $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    var term = this.term.split(' ').join('|');
                    var re = new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi");
                    var t = item.label.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>");
                    return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + t + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
                };

                $.get(sURL, function (responseText) {
                    data = responseText.split('#');

                    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                        //source: availableSports
                        source: data,
                        minLength: 2 

                    });

                });

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="ui-widget">
                <label for="tbAuto">
                    Enter data:
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="autosuggest" onkeyup="loadData();" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hopefully it'll help someone as it helped me.